# Setting annotationProcessor in maven-compiler-plugin then @Slf4j doesnt work : cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I added an annotation processor and set it in maven:

```maven
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <annotationProcessors>
                <annotationProcessor>
                    com.SpringLearn.cloud.processer.XXXProcessor
                </annotationProcessor>
            </annotationProcessors>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When maven compiles, it throws an error: `XXXService.java:[106,17] cannot find symbol`

at **XXXService.java:[106,17]** :

```java
log.info("startNewHand XXX:"+XXX);
```

CLEARLY, @Slf4j doesnt work
How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add the lombok dependency in your pom.xml and you might need to add a lombok plugin to your IDE.

Comment: Also, we would need to see how you are declaring the log in your service

Comment: I declaring the log by add @Slf4j on class,and it work good before set annotationProcessor in maven-compiler-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found that the logging mechanism is not available before calling the processor.

The solution was to use Messager from `javax.annotation.processing`.

```
messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, String.format("some-log message here"));
```